# How to make portable exe which extracts one program file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, exe

I've developed a WPF Application which needs some supporting DLLs in it to run.
So, in release folder I've got all the stuff that I need to run my application.

Now, I want to make an exe which actually can extract this release folder to some locations in the machine that I specify and creates a desktop shortcut.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe they call it an install file

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll definitely look into it..!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make an installer project in visual studio. Have a look at [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Comment: Thank you..! I will look into it.